# Need to print with spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to print name with spaces, can u help me please?
I got the code like this:

```
class Perfil:
    def __init__(self,email,nome,cidade):
        self.email=email
        self.nome=nome
        self.cidade=cidade

    def __str__(self):
        return "Perfil de "+self.nome+" ""("+self.email+")"" de "+self.cidade

    def getCidade(self):
        return self.cidade

    def setCidade(self,novo):
        self.cidade=novo

    def getDominio(self):
        t=self.email.rpartition("@")
        return t[2]

    def limpaNome(self):
        new=""
        if self.nome.isalpha()==True:
            return self.nome
        else:
            for i in self.nome:
                if i.isalpha()==True:
                    new +=i
        return new
```

When i run the program:

```
>>> p=Perfil("lol@mail.pt","Ze Car231los", "Porto")
>>> p.limpaNome()
'ZeCarlos'
```

I need a print like 'Ze Carlos' (with space)

Basically i need to wrote a program using abstract data types (class Profile) to save information for each user. Each object got the following attributes:

```
email
name
city
```

The class should have the following methods to manipulate the objects above

```
Method
__init__(self, email, name, city) - constructor
__str__(self)
getCity(self) - return the value of atribute city
getCity(self.new) - return the atribute city with a new value
getDomain(self) - example: lol@mail.com sugestion: use the method partition (i have to return mail.com only)
cleanName(self) - change the atribute name, deleting characters WICH are not alphabetic or spaces sugestion: use method isalpha
```

Comment: Whose code is this? I feel like if you wrote it, you'd know why it works that way.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is remove all occurrences of `'0'`,`'1'`,`'2'`,...,`'9'` from the string, then you could use `str.translate` like this:

```
def limpaNome(self):
    return self.nome.translate({ord(c):None for c in '0123456789'})
```

---

Note that there is no need for getters/setters like this in Python:

```
def getCidade(self):
    return self.cidade

def setCidade(self,novo):
    self.cidade=novo
```

Instead, just let the user access/set the attribute directly: `self.cidade`. If, at some point, you'd like to run a function whenever the attribute is accessed or assigned to, then you can make `cidade` a [property](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) *without having to change the usage syntax*.

---

You could even make `getDominio` and `limpaNome` properties too:

```
@property
def dominio(self):
    t=self.email.rpartition("@")
    return t[2]

@property
def limpaNome(self):
    return self.nome.translate({ord(c):None for c in '0123456789'})
```

Notice you don't need paretheses when accessing or setting the property. The syntax looks the same as though `lipaNome` were a plain attribute:

```
>>> p=Perfil("lol@mail.pt","Ze Car231los", "Porto")
>>> p.limpaNome
Ze Carllos
>>> p.dominio
mail.pt
```

Comment: I love the use of properties here, but IMO for variables that won't change much (if at all!) it's silly to add that overhead for what should be a simple attribute access. Maybe use a `dominio.setter` to assign `self.dominio_` to `self.email.rpartition("@")[2]` then the `dominio.getter` returns `self.dominio_`, but....

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

# ... the rest of your code
# ...

    def limpaNome(self):
        whitelist = set(string.ascii_uppercase+string.ascii_lowercase+" ")
        if self.nome.isalpha():
            return self.nome
        else:
            return ''.join(ch for ch in self.nome if ch in whitelist)
```

Or with regex:

```
import re

# ...
# ...

    def limpaNome(self):
        return re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z ]",'',self.nome)
```

Note that if I were you, I'd do:

```
class Perfil:
    def __init__(self, email, nome, cidade):
        self.email = email
        self.cidade = cidade
        self.nome = limpaNome(nome)
```